# audioStreamer swift error cocoa.h

Tags: swift, cocoa, audio, import, stream

I created an app in swift with a radio option, and i would like to get the metadata like artist title etc... so I import a 2 files (audioStreamer.m & audioStreamer.h) from Mike Jablonski project. They are cocoa file and when i'm running my project i got something like

```
cocoa/cocoa.h file not found.
```

I already saw some question like that on stackoverflow or google but it doesnt help.

https://code.google.com/p/audiostreamer-meta/ (original project)

Thanks for help (sorry for my english)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just delete all the :

```
 #ifdef TARGET_OS_IPHONE...
```

and just keep the :

```
 #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
```